# Angularjs - Add multiple params to $resource

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am calling a spring mvc rest resource from Angularjs with $resource.

**Angularjs**

Factory :

```
.factory('EnvoiBl', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/envoiBl/:noBl', {}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET', isArray:true,
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

Call:

```
EnvoiBl.get({noBl:vente.noBl}
```

**Java side**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envoiBl/{noBl}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void envoiBlToClient(@PathVariable String noBl,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        blah blah blah
    }
```

I would like to send another parameter (in addition of noBl), let's say : 'record' (a string).
How can I do to add this new parameter in both sides?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular url can be parameterized just like the `:noBi` you can add `$resource('api/envoiBl/:noBl/:anotherParam', {}, {`

The usage on the client side will be something like `EnvoiBl.query({noBl:itsValue, anotherParam:thisOtherValue},function(data){\\process})`
and on the java side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envoiBl/{noBl}/{anotherParam}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
    public void envoiBlToClient(@PathVariable("noBl") noBl,@PathVariable("anotherParam") String anotherParam,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS

```
.factory('EnvoiBl', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/envoiBl/:noBl:record', {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET', isArray:true,
            params: {noBl: '@noBl', record: @record},
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Java side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/envoiBl/{noBl}/{record}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void envoiBlToClient(@PathVariable String noBl, @PathVariable String record, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        blah blah blah
    }
```